# Prime the website using Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I really hope to find some answers here as i tried everything by now.

Background:
Overtime we deploy code to web server, we need to do a cache warm up, i.e. access the site and make sure it loads. First load is always the slowest since IIS require to do some manipulations with a new code and cache it.

Task:
Create a page which will a checkbox and a button. Once button is pressed, array of links sent to server. Server visits each link and provides a feedback on time it took to load each page to the user.

Solution:
I am using node JS & express JS on server side. So far i manage to POST array to the server with links, but since i have limited experience with node JS, i can not figure out server side code to work.

Here is a code i got so far (it is bits and pieces, but it gives an idea of my progress). Any help will be greatly appreciated!!!

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

var http = require("http");


function siteToPrime(url){
    http.get(url, function (http_res) {

        // initialize the container for our data
        var data = "";

        // this event fires many times, each time collecting another piece of the response
        http_res.on("data", function (chunk) {

            // append this chunk to our growing `data` var
            data += chunk;
        });

        // this event fires *one* time, after all the `data` events/chunks have been gathered
        http_res.on("end", function () {
            // you can use res.send instead of console.log to output via express
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
};

//Tells express where to look for static content
app.use(express.static('public'));

app.post('/', parseUrlencoded, function(request, response){
    var newBlock = request.body;
    console.log(Object.keys(newBlock).length);

    var key = Object.keys(newBlock)[0];
    console.log(newBlock[key]);
    siteToPrime("www.google.com");

    response.status(201);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000...");
});
```

Comment: the array of sites are coming to the server side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have access to the array in the post route:

```
var express = require("express"),
    request = require("request"),
    app = express();

var start = new Date();

app.use(express.static('public'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));


function siteToPrime(req, res, urls) {
    urls.forEach(function(url)) {
        request(url, function(error, res, body) {
            if (!error && res.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(url +' : ' + body);
                console.log('Request took: ', new Date() - start, 'ms');
            }
        });
    }
    res.redirect('/');
};




app.post('/', function(req, res){
    var urls = req.body.urls // Array os urls.

    siteToPrime(req, res, urls);
});


app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on port 3000...");
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!!! It all worked and gives me a head start on my project. I did only small change as new version of express was complaining about: app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false})); so i changed it to var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var parseUrlencoded = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false});

Comment: i am glad i help u :)